# Why does a join on ROW_NUMBER() between common table expressions result in a Cartesian product?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am joining two common table expressions (cte) based on an id created within each cte using ROW_NUMBER(). The resulting execution plan includes a Merge Join where the Estimated Rows are *13,530,000,000* in my case; and the actual number of rows ends up being about *13,000*.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do, and this results in a similar execution plan with *1,200,000,000* estimated rows in the Merge Join, and *12,000* actual rows.

I am stuck understanding why what seems like a simple join is creating a Cartesian product.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Product;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product_Id') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Product_Id;

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    [rowId] int identity primary key,
    [id] int
    )

CREATE TABLE #Product_Id (
    [id] int primary key
    )

DECLARE @Id int

SET @Id = 500000
WHILE @Id <= 600000
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO #Product_Id 
   VALUES (@Id)
   SET @Id += 1
END

SET @Id = 1
WHILE @Id <= 12000
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO #Product 
   VALUES (NULL)
   SET @Id += 1
END

WITH
PRODUCT_ID_CTE AS (
    SELECT [id],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id]) AS [rn]
      FROM #Product_Id
),
PRODUCT_CTE AS (
    SELECT [id],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [rowId]) AS [rn]
      FROM #Product
)

SELECT ISNULL(a.[id], b.[id]) AS [id]
  FROM PRODUCT_CTE a
  JOIN PRODUCT_ID_CTE b
    ON a.[rn] = b.[rn]
```

[Execution plan with CTE](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJMzvgRXw)

[Execution plan with sub queries](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SygBDxCQw)

Comment: Stale statistics? Does it improve if you `UPDATE STATISTICS #Product WITH FULLSCAN; UPDATE STATISTICS #Product_Id WITH FULLSCAN;` before your CTE?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the statistics for temp tables are created on the first query execution, so updating the statistics before the cte's doesn't have any affect.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts yes, they are created on the first execution. And they're cached for #temp tables between invocations, so if you're running multiple queries with the same #temp tables you can get stale statistics (even if you drop and recreate them).

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning. I should have mentioned that the statistics are up to date; and, updating the statistics was one of the things I looked at. The actual query is performed on two tables with existing data.